# Measure theory and existence of set integral

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose $f\in \mathcal{L}^p$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there exists a set $E \in S$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ such that if $F\in \mathcal{S}$ and $F\cap E=\varnothing$ then $||f\chi_{F}||_p<\epsilon$

My attempt was to do something like:

For $f\in \mathcal{L}^p$, clearly $|f|^p \in \mathcal{L}^1$. Put $E_n=\{ x\in X$ $:$ $|f|^p(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$

Then, $|f|^p\chi_{E_n}\leq |f|^p$ . Since $|f|^p\chi_{E_n} \rightarrow |f|^p$  as $n\rightarrow \infty$ , we get by DCT that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int |f|^p \chi_{E_n} d\mu= \int |f|^p d\mu <\infty$.

How do I complete the proof? Is it possible from this stage?

Comment: Sorry for asking but is this a question from Elements of Integration - Bartle?

Comment: @PAM1499 yes, it is. Problem 6.P. this is where I got it from

Comment: try using 4.S... It should help I believe

Comment: Or this might help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356354/mue-epsilon-infty-such-that-if-f-cap-e-epsilon-emptyset-then?rq=1

Comment: @PAM1499 how do I complete my attempt?

Comment: Use the definition of limit with a "smart "$\epsilon$ (remember you will have to raise to $\frac{1}{p}$) now to get an inequality. Then use the fact that you can split the integral of $f$ on the integral of $f$ over $F$ plus the integral over E. The integral over E should cancel on both sides I believe

Comment: @PAM1499 would $E$ be $E_n$ in my attempt? or some other set?

Comment: Yes... For some n large enough.

Comment: @PAM1499 so $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I believe it finishs your proof if everything you did is correct just by raising to the power $\frac{1}{p}$ the last inequality. I hope it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have
$$
\lim\int_{E_n}|f|^p=\int |f|^p
$$
choose $N$ big enough such that
$$
\int |f|^p < \int_{E_N}|f|^p + \epsilon^p.
$$
Then for $E=E_N$ and for any $F \cap E=\emptyset$
$$
\int_F |f|^p+\int_{E_N}|f|^p \leq \int |f|^p < \int_{E_N}|f|^p + \epsilon^p.
$$
Then
$$
\int_F |f|^p<  \epsilon^p.
$$

Comment: do you mean $F\cap E_N=\varnothing?$

Comment: Yes!!! Sorry, my bad

Comment: This does indeed complete my proof. Thanks!!!

Comment: You are welcome! ;)